How do you use OAuth access tokens to authenticate subsequent requests
I'm trying to understand how to use the OAuth (authorization code) flow in the context of securing a backend API. Not sure if it matters, but I'll be using Passport.js to implement social logins (google, facebook, etc...).
I think I understand the basics of the flow thanks to articles like:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/22/the-complete-guide-to-protecting-your-apis-with-oauth2/
https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/04/14/the-authorization-code-grant-in-excruciating-detail/
https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow

and that at the end of the flow you get the user profile as registered with the provider (google profile, facebook profile info) along with access/refresh tokens. That's all well and good but I don't understand how I can then use that when my client app makes a request to my backend server after logging in? How does my backend know whether the access token is still valid without making another request to the identity provider? In order to verify the token (if it is a JWT) is the secret the same as the one I'm given by the provider (OAUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET for google for example)?
I'd appreciate more info or links on that subject (client/server interaction after the OAuth flow)!
Read articles on OAuth but pretty much all of them are focused on the actual flow, not what comes after that
